# shell command to remove characters after a special character in bash/shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have filename

```
hello_1.0_25.tgz
a_hello_1.25.6_154.tgz
<name>_<name1>.tgz
```

The output which i need is

```
hello_1.0
a_hello_1.25.6
<name>
```

How can i get string before special character `_` in bash (or) shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, this is easy:

```
$ f=hello_1.0_25.tgz
$ echo "${f%_*}"
hello_1.0
```

`${f%_*}` simply removes the `_` and anything after it from the end of the variable `f`.

This is more concise than other approaches that use external tools and also saves using an extra process when one isn't needed.

[more tips on string manipulation in bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Comment: Always good to use the correct tool for the job. Good old `parameter expansion w/substring extraction`. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
sed -r 's/(.*)_.*/\1/'
```

**Test**

```
$ echo "hello_1.0_25.tgz" | sed -r 's/(.*)_.*/\1/'
hello_1.0
$ echo "a_hello_1.25.6_154.tgz" | sed -r 's/(.*)_.*/\1/'
a_hello_1.25.6
$ echo "<name>_<name1>.tgz" | sed -r 's/(.*)_.*/\1/'
<name>
```

**What it does?**

- `s` substitute command
- `(.*)` matches anything till the last `_` . Saved in `\1`
- `_.*` matches `_` followed by the rest
- `/\1/` replaced with `\1`, first capture group

**OR**

```
sed -r 's/_[^_]+$//'
```

**Test**

```
$ echo "hello_1.0_25.tgz" | sed -r 's/_[^_]+$//'
hello_1.0
$ echo "a_hello_1.25.6_154.tgz"  | sed -r 's/_[^_]+$//'
a_hello_1.25.6
$ echo "<name>_<name1>.tgz"   | sed -r 's/_[^_]+$//'
<name>
```

**What it does?**

- `[^_]+` Matches anything other than `_`. `+` quantifes the previous pattern one or more times
- `$` matches the end of the line
- `//` replaced with empty

Comment: can you please give explanation also so that concept will be clear?

Comment: @user3003758 you are welcome :) I have added an explanation. Hope its clear for you now

Answer (score 1):

this **sed** line should do:

```
sed 's/_[^_]*$//'
```

little test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
hello_1.0_25.tgz
a_hello_1.25.6_154.tgz
<name>_<name1>.tgz

kent$  sed 's/_[^_]*$//' f
hello_1.0
a_hello_1.25.6
<name>
```

**awk** can do it for sure too:

```
kent$  awk -F_ -v OFS="_" 'NF--' f
hello_1.0
a_hello_1.25.6
<name>
```

or **grep** if you like:

```
kent$  grep -Po '.*(?=_[^_]*$)' f
hello_1.0
a_hello_1.25.6
<name>
```

and @Tom Fenech 's bash way is nice too.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk  -F_ '{$NF="";sub(/_$/,"")}1' OFS=_ file
hello_1.0
a_hello_1.25.6
<name>
```

`-F_` Sets Field Separator to `_`
`$NF=""` Removes last field.
`sub(/_$/,"")` Removes last filed separator.
`1` Prints out all lines.

Comment: Awk is probably overkill (if you don't explain it).

Comment: `awk -F_ 'NF--' OFS=_ file`

Comment: @Jidder This will fail if there is a blank line, since `NF` becomes negative. This will work without error, but removes the blank line `awk -F_ 'NF&&NF--' OFS=_ file`

Comment: Isn't OP doing this on filenames ? It is very unlikely to have a blank line. If it did though and you want to preserve them you can use `awk -F_ '!NF||NF--' OFS=_ file`

Comment: @Pureferret I do agree and have added comment.  `awk` may in may cases be simpler to understand than  a complex `regex` in `sed`

Comment: @Jidder That is true :)  I do also see another problems in all the solution here.  If file does not have `_` it will be removed (prints a blank line)

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on `substring extraction`:

```
$ m="a_hello_1.25.6_154.tgz"
$ echo "${m/%_${m/#*_/}/}"
$ a_hello_1.25.6
```

Which basically says `${m/#*_/}` **find the text following the last `_`** = `154.tgz` (call it `stuff`); and then **remove it, preceded by an underscore, from the backend of the string** `${m/%_stuff/}`. For a complete expression of `${m/%_${m/#*_/}/}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
sed 's/\(.*\)_\.*/\1/g' file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bash regular expressions:

```
$ f=hello_1.0_25.tgz
$ if [[ $f =~ (.*)_.*\.tgz$ ]]; then echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; fi
hello_1.0
```